# Store array from cloud firestore into variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called users. Each document has the ids of posts they have saved in an array. Is it possible to put this array into a variable and have it in a `Text()` widget? Essentially the text widget output would look like this on screen oMqSYa97CteaDr19lZ5Ga6WO4jn8oPJREOcJWLI2.

I have searched for this solution, but haven't found any luck.

I've tried a few things, but usually end up with Instance of 'Future DocomentSnapshot'

[image: image showing array]

Answer (score 1):

you should share your code for us to learn what you did and why do you face with that oMqSYa97CteaDr19lZ5Ga6WO4jn8oPJREOcJWLI2. However, firstly, you should create a model like that

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  UserData({ this.uid, this.sugars, this.strength, this.name });

}
```

and an instance;

```
  final CollectionReference UsersCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
```

and you can use it like that ;

```
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data()['name'],
      sugars: snapshot.data()['sugars'],
      strength: snapshot.data()['strength'],
    );
  }

  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return UsersCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

finally;

```
UserData userData = snapshot.data.sugars;
```